# How can add drawable image to recyclerview imageview in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want add drawable image to recyclerview imageview.
Drawable image Resource:r_300_x_300_2.png,
                        r_300_x_300_3.png,
                        r_300_x_300_4.png

Check my activity and recyclerviewadapter code.
(prevent more details.)
(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)(prevent more details.)

```
   private val tag = this::class.java.simpleName


   var historylist: MutableList<HistoryItemDataVo> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history)

        swipeRefreshLo.setOnRefreshListener(this)

        historylist.add(HistoryItemDataVo("item1",30000))
        historylist.add(HistoryItemDataVo("item2",20000))
        historylist.add(HistoryItemDataVo("item3",30000))
        historylist.add(HistoryItemDataVo("item4",30000))
        historylist.add(HistoryItemDataVo("item5",30000))


        val itemRecyclerAdapter = HistoryitemReclycerViewAdapter(this, historylist)

        recyclerview.adapter = itemRecyclerAdapter
        recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)

    }

    override fun onRefresh() {
        swipeRefreshLo.isRefreshing = false }
}
```

````
class HistoryItemDataVo(title: String, pointValue: Int) {

    var title: String = title
    var pointValue: Int = pointValue



}
class HistoryitemReclycerViewAdapter(private var activity: Activity, private var dataList: MutableList<HistoryItemDataVo>): RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryitemReclycerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolderItem(inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_item_list, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val data = dataList[position]

        var h = holder as ViewHolderItem
        h.titleText.text =data.title
        h.pointValueText.text = data.pointValue.toString() + "P"


    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size

    open inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    inner class ViewHolderItem(itemView: View): ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText) as TextView
        var pointValueText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pointValueText) as TextView
        var imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)as ImageView

    }
}

```
````

Comment: So what is your problem...?

Comment: i want to add r_300_x_300_2.png to Recyclerview imageView . onBindViewHolder u can see just text setting.

Comment: `h.imageView.setImageDrawable()`